# как скрыть ответ класса в php

Tags: php

Я обращаюсь к классу в php

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $u = PrivilegedUser::getByUsername($_SESSION['username']);
    print_r($u);
}
```

После того как класс отработал, он возвращает объект, заполненный информацией о соответствующем пользователе и его правах доступа. В качестве прав доступа у меня в базе в одной из таблиц хранится `html` код страницы. При обращении к классу и выводе содержимого на страницу он мне показывает лабуду с моим html кодом из базы данных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как избавиться от этих надписей?

UPD:

```
public static function getByUsername($username) {
        $obj = new DB();
        $DB = $obj->connectdb();
        $query = "select * from users where username = :username";
        $sth = $DB->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute(
            array(
                ":username" => $username
            )
        );
        
        $result = $sth->fetch();
        
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $privUser = new PrivilegedUser();
            $privUser->user_id = $result["id"];
            $privUser->username = $username;
            $privUser->initRoles();
            return $privUser;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

`getByUsername` это метод класса `PrivilegedUser` он возвращает объект, заполненный информацией о соответствующем пользователе. метод `initRoles` для хранит `id и имя роли`. например `1 Администратор` и т.д)

```
protected function initRoles() {
        $this->roles = array();
        $obj = new DB();
        $DB = $obj->connectdb();
        $query = "select t1.role_id, t2.name from user_role as t1 join role as t2 on t1.role_id = t2.id_role where t1.user_id = :user_id";
        $sth = $DB->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute(
            array(
                ":user_id" => $this->user_id
            )
        );

        while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $this->roles[$result["name"]] = Role::getRoleContent($result["role_id"]);
        }
    }
```

`getRoleContent` метод класса `Role` возвращает контент из базы данных в соответствии с ролью пользователя

```
public static function getRoleContent($role_id) {
        $role = new Role();
        $obj = new DB();
        $DB = $obj->connectdb();
        $query = "select t2.content from role_content as t1 join content as t2 on t1.content_id = t2.id where t1.role_id = :role_id";
        $sth = $DB->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute(
            array(
                ":role_id" => $role_id
            )
        );

        while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $role->contents[$row["content"]] = true;
        }
        return $role;
        
        // $content = [];
        // while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        //     $content[] = $row["content"];
        // }
        // return $content;
    }
```

А вызываю я его вот так, `$_SESSION['username']` это `username` пользователя, например `demo`

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   $u = PrivilegedUser::getByUsername($_SESSION['username']);
   print_r($u);
}
```

Comment: `$u` - действительно не строка. Чтобы получить данные, надо к ним обратиться. А если сделать `$u['Администратор']['contents:protected']`?

Comment: Так данные получаются без проблем) В общем сейчас попробую разобраться сам еще, если что выложу ответ на свой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

> он мне показывает лабуду. Как избавиться?

Не писать в коде эту самую лабуду в виде

```
print_r($u);
```

Comment: мда.. слишком полезный комментарий)) Подскажите плиз куда копать хотя бы

Comment: мда...человек не умеет глядеть в собственный код...

Comment: ладно print_r, но почему тогда echo не работает?

Comment: ты нормально сформулируй для начала вопрос.... сейчас нет никаких echo и никто на планете Земля не знает что для тебя значит "не работает". ..........Сейчас был конкретный вопрос про "лабуду" и конкретный ответ на это

Comment: Понятно короч. echo не показывает на странице ничего кроме белого экрана. print_r отображает хоть что-то. Скрин Вам о чем-то говорит? echo я полагаю не работает только потому что это явно не строка.

Comment: Если человек не понимает в php или пытается разобраться, не надо грубить, ухмыляться, рофлить для начала.

Comment: Чтобы нормально формулировать вопрос - не нужно знание какого-то языка программирования, нужен просто мозг..... В итоге у тебя вопрос об одном, а комментарии совсем о другом...

Comment: И обиженку не надо включать. Минусы ставить и винить других. Если нормально не можешь объяснить проблему, то остальные вокруг в этом не виноваты.

Comment: обиженку никто не включал. а Ваш ответ пользы для меня не принес, я расценил это как грубость с Вашей стороны, поэтому минус, извините. Сижу, пытаюсь переформулировать вопрос. Видимо мозги уже вытекли от этой фиготы что даже вопрос правильно не могу оформить. print_r я использовал для тестирования. echo в моем случае не работает, т.к. судя по всему это не строка `Object of class PrivilegedUser could not be converted to string`. Можно ли достать массив со строками из базы данных из объекта класса? Или для этого необходимо использовать `json_decode(json_encode($u), true);`

Comment: PrivilegedUser - это не встроенный класс php, поэтому вряд ли кто, кроме его автора, может ответить на этот вопрос. Либо тебе придётся самому разобраться, что это за класс, что он делает и какие у него есть возможности. В любом случае, использование класса, который неизвестно как работает - прохая практика.

Comment: @nonadminus  ответ расценен как грубость. Забавно........как доставать данные из класса, который никто, кроме тебя не видит - никто, кроме тебя сказать не сможет. А вообще я бы посоветовал для начала изучить основы языка. Потому что тут налицо явное их незнание базы

Comment: Немного расширил свой вопрос.

Comment: А вообще да, было бы здорово прочесть что-то по ооп php, если можете, посоветуйте плиз. Объекты, массивы, куча всяких функций, всего не упомнишь, нужна практика, а когда дело доходит до этого, то всегда ступор, непонимание, чтение логов, гугление и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял, что при таком обращении `PrivilegedUser::getByUsername($_SESSION['username']);` вы получаете не массив, не строку, а объект. И `print_r($u);` выводит всё его описание. Чтобы от этого избавится надо было обратиться к данным `$u['Администратор']['contents:protected']`.

Но в дальнейшем это усложнит разработку, также как непонятные имена методов (`getByUsername` гет чего по Username?). Попробуйте в методе `getByUsername` возвращать именно строку и переименовать его в `getUserContent`. Тогда Вам самому будет проще это использовать. Да и не только в нём. Лучше использовать специальные отдельные методы (гетеры) для получения необходимых данных. Например, `getUserContent($idUser)` или `getUserRole($idUser)`

Comment: "гет чего по Username"  --- как чего, привелегированных пользователей... ведь метод относится к `PrivilegedUser`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я к тому, что тут лучше разнести на несколько методов. Например, получить контент. В данном месте, как я вижу, не все же полученные значения используются